# PHP echo HTML file

Tags: php, html, echo

i am trying to echo a html files contents from a php script. Quite simple implementation

```
$response=file_get_contents("second.html");

echo $response;
```

When i hit the html file directly all the content seems ok but when i get the echoed string it is different, The html contains javascript with utf8 strings and escape characters. It seems that "echo" is changing the string because i tried saving the $response string in a second html file and that appears ok also. My question is, is there a way to just plainly give the string with no processing.

Also it seems the echoed html works on firefox, but not on chrome, the file html works on both.

Comment: Are you calling a local file?

Comment: whats the encoding of the 2 pages?

Comment: echo is not adding javascript or escape characters. Are you working inside of a framework?

Comment: You can combine those two lines into one by doing: `readfile('second.html');`.

Comment: I can try combining but i will need to process the html later on so that cant be an option.

Comment: encoding is utf8 both on the file, and the html.

Comment: So something is escaping, is magic quotes on? Etc?

Comment: Show us what the difference in output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get if you do:

```
var_export(get_magic_quotes_gpc());
```

Is it on? (true)

If so:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

or

```
$response = stripslashes(file_get_contents("second.html"));
```

Comment: Magic quotes are on, and the second does not work, because as i said the string is read perfectly, i tried a file_put_contents before the echo and it was ok and different from the echoed string.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you're not telling the browser what encoding you're using?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: I'm in the same case. The header was already there and plain text is showing. Going to try suggestions above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to view the HTML as plain text, you can run a PHP script to find and replace the "<" and ">" characters to HTML entities using 'str_replace()'. [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp)

Then when you echo, PHP handles them as "<" and ">" in plain text not HTML at ALL.

Learn more about find and replace in PHP using str_replace():

[str_replace PHP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)

Example:

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents("second.html");
str_replace("<", "&lt;",$response);
str_replace(">", "&gt;",$response;
echo $response;
?>
```